# Cumsum a column's values for last 12 months for each row pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like this for each ID;

| Months | ID | AnnualSalaryChange |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-11-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-10-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-09-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-08-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-07-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-06-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-05-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-04-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-03-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-02-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-12-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2019-11-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-10-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-09-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-08-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-07-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-06-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-05-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-04-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-03-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-02-01 | 1 | 1 |

And I want a column like AnnualSalaryChangeSumFor12Months. It should be cumulative sum of AnnualSalaryChange values for last 12 months(changeable) for each row. For each row it should go back 12 months ago and sum the values up to that time. If there are no 12 rows to sum, it can sum the remaining rows.

| Months | ID | AnnualSalaryChange | AnnualSalaryChangeSumFor12Months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2020-11-01 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2020-10-01 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2020-09-01 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2020-08-01 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2020-07-01 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2020-06-01 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2020-05-01 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2020-04-01 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2020-03-01 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020-02-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2019-12-01 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2019-11-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2019-10-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2019-09-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2019-08-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2019-07-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2019-06-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2019-05-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2019-04-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2019-03-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2019-02-01 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I tried;

```
df['ChangeSum']=df.groupby(['ID','Year'])['AnnualSalaryChange'].cumsum()
```

But it doesn't give what I really want. How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Why for row `2020-02-01` is `AnnualSalaryChangeSumFor12Months = 1` ?

Comment: Hi, the last few rows were missing. I edited it, it will be clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this `df`:

```
        Months  ID  AnnualSalaryChange
0   2020-12-01   1                   0
1   2020-11-01   1                   1
2   2020-10-01   1                   0
3   2020-09-01   1                   0
4   2020-08-01   1                   0
5   2020-07-01   1                   0
6   2020-06-01   1                   0
7   2020-05-01   1                   0
8   2020-04-01   1                   0
9   2020-03-01   1                   1
10  2020-02-01   1                   0
11  2020-01-01   1                   0
12  2019-12-01   1                   1
13  2019-11-01   1                   0
14  2019-10-01   1                   0
15  2019-09-01   1                   0
16  2019-08-01   1                   0
17  2019-07-01   1                   0
18  2019-06-01   1                   0
19  2019-05-01   1                   0
20  2019-04-01   1                   0
21  2019-03-01   1                   0
22  2019-02-01   1                   1
23  2020-12-01   2                   0
24  2020-11-01   2                   1
25  2020-10-01   2                   0
26  2020-09-01   2                   0
27  2020-08-01   2                   0
28  2020-07-01   2                   0
29  2020-06-01   2                   0
30  2020-05-01   2                   0
31  2020-04-01   2                   0
32  2020-03-01   2                   1
33  2020-02-01   2                   0
34  2020-01-01   2                   0
35  2019-12-01   2                   1
36  2019-11-01   2                   0
37  2019-10-01   2                   0
38  2019-09-01   2                   0
39  2019-08-01   2                   0
40  2019-07-01   2                   0
41  2019-06-01   2                   0
42  2019-05-01   2                   0
43  2019-04-01   2                   0
44  2019-03-01   2                   0
45  2019-02-01   2                   1
```

You can do:

```py
df["Months"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Months"])
df = df.sort_values(by="Months")

df_out = (
    df.groupby("ID")
    .rolling(on="Months", window=12, min_periods=1)["AnnualSalaryChange"]
    .sum()
    .reset_index()
    .sort_values(by=["ID", "Months"], ascending=[True, False])
).rename(columns={"AnnualSalaryChange": "AnnualSalaryChangeSumFor12Months"})
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
    ID     Months  AnnualSalaryChangeSumFor12Months
22   1 2020-12-01                               2.0
21   1 2020-11-01                               3.0
20   1 2020-10-01                               2.0
19   1 2020-09-01                               2.0
18   1 2020-08-01                               2.0
17   1 2020-07-01                               2.0
16   1 2020-06-01                               2.0
15   1 2020-05-01                               2.0
14   1 2020-04-01                               2.0
13   1 2020-03-01                               2.0
12   1 2020-02-01                               1.0
11   1 2020-01-01                               2.0
10   1 2019-12-01                               2.0
9    1 2019-11-01                               1.0
8    1 2019-10-01                               1.0
7    1 2019-09-01                               1.0
6    1 2019-08-01                               1.0
5    1 2019-07-01                               1.0
4    1 2019-06-01                               1.0
3    1 2019-05-01                               1.0
2    1 2019-04-01                               1.0
1    1 2019-03-01                               1.0
0    1 2019-02-01                               1.0
45   2 2020-12-01                               2.0
44   2 2020-11-01                               3.0
43   2 2020-10-01                               2.0
42   2 2020-09-01                               2.0
41   2 2020-08-01                               2.0
40   2 2020-07-01                               2.0
39   2 2020-06-01                               2.0
38   2 2020-05-01                               2.0
37   2 2020-04-01                               2.0
36   2 2020-03-01                               2.0
35   2 2020-02-01                               1.0
34   2 2020-01-01                               2.0
33   2 2019-12-01                               2.0
32   2 2019-11-01                               1.0
31   2 2019-10-01                               1.0
30   2 2019-09-01                               1.0
29   2 2019-08-01                               1.0
28   2 2019-07-01                               1.0
27   2 2019-06-01                               1.0
26   2 2019-05-01                               1.0
25   2 2019-04-01                               1.0
24   2 2019-03-01                               1.0
23   2 2019-02-01                               1.0
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted. I'm appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Months'])
df['AnnualSalaryChangeSumFor12Months'] = df['AnnualSalaryChange'].rolling(window=12, min_periods=1).sum()
df = df.sort_values(['Months'], ascending=False)
```

With groupby it is very similar, but a bit longer:

```
df = df1.sort_values(['ID', 'Months'])
df['AnnualSalaryChangeSumFor12Months'] = df.reset_index(drop=True).groupby(['ID'])['AnnualSalaryChange'].rolling(window=12, min_periods=1).sum().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Months'], ascending=False)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you it works but when I add `groupby('ID')` i got this error: `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index` . How can I add groupby?

Comment: Why do you want to add groupby? Isn't the result already  what you wanted?

Comment: There are many IDs and I should be able to do this for each of them.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm appreciated.