# Computing yoy changes for multiple clients in same column in dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with four columns:

- Client ID
- Date
- Assets
- Flows

Not all clients have data for the full set of dates. In such case, rows are missing. Put differently, I don't have the same number of rows for each client.

I would like to compute the following and add in additional columns:

- Absolute and relative change in Assets over 12m and 3m
- Sum of Flows over 12m and 3m

When statistics can't be computed (i.e. the first 11m), the column should be filled with nan.

I have tried with group, however can't find a way around the fact that the length of data for each client is different.

Here is an example of my data (first 4 columns) and the wished result (last 4 columns), done in Excel:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEfdM.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in monthly changes you can add column "months_since" which would equal number of months since a certain date.

```
df.pivot("months_since", "Client ID", "Assets")
```

To get a matrix representation of your data. If certain client is a missing an observation he would have a nan value.

Then it is easy to compute sums/delta using df.rolling(12).sum() or df.diff(12)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df_data = pd.read_excel('sample2.xlsx')

df_result_change_assets_3m = df_data.pivot_table(values = 'Assets', index = ['Client ID','Date']).unstack(['Client ID']).pct_change(3).unstack(['Date'])['Assets'].reset_index().rename(columns = {0:'Change Assets 3m (%)'})

df_result_change_assets_12m = df_data.pivot_table(values = 'Assets', index = ['Client ID','Date']).unstack(['Client ID']).pct_change(12).unstack(['Date'])['Assets'].reset_index().rename(columns = {0:'Change Assets 12m (%)'})

df_result_change_usd_assets_3m = df_data.pivot_table(values = 'Assets', index = ['Client ID','Date']).unstack(['Client ID'])
df_result_change_usd_assets_3m = df_result_change_usd_assets_3m - df_result_change_usd_assets_3m.shift(3)
df_result_change_usd_assets_3m = df_result_change_usd_assets_3m.unstack(['Date'])['Assets'].reset_index().rename(columns = {0:'Change Assets 3m (USD)'})

df_result_change_usd_assets_12m = df_data.pivot_table(values = 'Assets', index = ['Client ID','Date']).unstack(['Client ID'])
df_result_change_usd_assets_12m = df_result_change_usd_assets_12m - df_result_change_usd_assets_12m.shift(12)
df_result_change_usd_assets_12m = df_result_change_usd_assets_12m.unstack(['Date'])['Assets'].reset_index().rename(columns = {0:'Change Assets 12m (USD)'})


df_data = df_data.merge(df_result_change_assets_3m, how = 'left', on = ['Client ID','Date'])
df_data = df_data.merge(df_result_change_assets_12m, how = 'left', on = ['Client ID','Date'])
df_data = df_data.merge(df_result_change_usd_assets_3m, how = 'left', on = ['Client ID','Date'])
df_data = df_data.merge(df_result_change_usd_assets_12m, how = 'left', on = ['Client ID','Date'])

df_data
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to split the problem in two: first you calculate the yoy on assets, than you can focus on flow. For the first task you can create two new columns to merge data using a self join. You can create the new columns using [`pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html#pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd) method as follow:

```
data_df['date_12MonthsAfter'] = data_df['date'] + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(12)
data_df['date_3MonthsAfter'] = data_df['date'] + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(3)
```

Than you can merge the data with two self join that calculate the quantity you need. There are a couple of ways to do that, I did it so:

```
data_merged_12Months = (data_df.merge(data_df[['clientId', 'date_12MonthsAfter', 'assets']], 
                                  left_on = ['clientId', 'date'], 
                                  right_on = ['clientId', 'date_12MonthsAfter'],
                                  how = 'left', 
                                  suffixes=['', '_prevYear'])).drop(['date_12MonthsAfter',
                                                                     'date_3MonthsAfter',
                                                                     'date_12MonthsAfter_prevYear'], axis = 1)
data_merged_3Months = (data_df.merge(data_df[['clientId', 'date_3MonthsAfter', 'assets']], 
                                 left_on = ['clientId', 'date'], 
                                 right_on = ['clientId', 'date_3MonthsAfter'],
                                 how = 'left', 
                                 suffixes=['', '_prevQuarter'])).drop(['assets',
                                                                       'flow',
                                                                       'date_12MonthsAfter',
                                                                       'date_3MonthsAfter',
                                                                       'date_3MonthsAfter_prevQuarter'], axis = 1)
data_merged_assets = data_merged_12Months.merge(data_merged_3Months, on = ['clientId', 'date'])
data_merged_assets['perc yoy'] = (data_merged_assets['assets'] - data_merged_assets['assets_prevYear'])/data_merged_assets['assets_prevYear']
data_merged_assets['perc qoq'] = (data_merged_assets['assets'] - data_merged_assets['assets_prevQuarter'])/data_merged_assets['assets_prevQuarter']
```

For the flow calculation, of flow you have to replace the blacket cells with zeros, you can do it with method `.str.replce('', '0')` and than you have to trasform the column data type in `int`. To calculate the last 12 and 3 months sum I find [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67494673/cumsum-a-columns-values-for-last-12-months-for-each-row-pandas)

```
data_merged_assets['flow'] = (data_merged_assets.str.replace('', '0')).astype(int)
data_flow_12Months = data_merged_assets.groupby(['clientId']).rolling(on = 'date', window=12, min_periods=12)["flow"].sum().reset_index()
data_flow_3Months = data_merged_assets.groupby(['clientId']).rolling(on = 'date', window=3, min_periods=3)["flow"].sum().reset_index()
data_flow = data_flow_12Months.merge(data_flow_3Months, on = ['clientId', 'date'], suffixes = ['_sumLast12Months', '_sumLast3Months'])
```

Finally, I merged the two datasets.

```
data_merged = data_merged_assets.merge(data_flow, on = ['clientId', 'date'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly. One issue when transforming the blank to 0:  it tells me "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'". I replaced with data_merged_assets['flow'] = data_merged_assets['flow'].fillna(0).astype(int) and it works.